# How can I dynamically select input field in dynamically generated forms with Javascript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

When my document is ready I have 1 or more identically forms with select and two inputs that I want to show (1 of them based on select dynamically).

For 1 form its pretty simple, but my problem is that forms are generated dynamically like when  I have on ready 1 form select tag is looking like this

```HTML
<button type="button" class="add-document-item btn btn-success btn-sm pull-right">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
</button>
<select id="type" class="form-control">
   <option value="1">File 1</option>
   <option value="2">File 2</option>
</select>

<div class="col-md-12 system" id="system">
   My YII2 active form field...                       
</div>
<div class="col-md-12 computer" id="computer">
   My YII2 active form field...                       
</div>
```

If after opening document and there is more than 1 form OR there is one and I adding more by myself dynamically, SELECT id's generating like "type0", "type1", "type2" and same is with form fields id's.

So far I can only switch inputs dynamically only when 1 form is rendered

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#computer').hide();
  $(document).on('change', '#type', function () {
     var val = $('#type').val();
     if (val == 2) {
       $('#system').show();
       $('#computer').hide();
     } else {
       $('#computer').show();
       $('#system').hide();
     }
   });
 });
```

My need is to change selected input for every generated form individual. I am stuck for this already for some time. Can anybody can help me?

Comment: I don't understand, if the `<form>`s are identical why have several?

Comment: Same forms -> different information

Comment: if your forms have different information they also have different field names and inputs, so they are not identical. why write that they are identical? what is the reasoning?

Comment: For whatever reason why identiacal foms are needed keep this in mind: you never have to use `#id` `.class` is always a better choice (even `[name]`), especially when you are using jQuery.

Comment: Let me know if my script works for you!

Answer (score 0):

This javascript I created should do the trick. You'll need to apply this to your own code.

1. Declare an array with all form elements
2. Select all elements you are going to loop through
3. Use forEach and overload it with the array you created
4. Create an if statement with the right filter set

   ```
    myArray = document.querySelectorAll('form')

    document.querySelectorAll('form').forEach(function(value, index,    
    myArray){

    if (myArray[index].getAttribute('id')=='system'){
    console.log('system') //doSomething()

    }
    })
   ```

You can refactor this by replacing the 2th instance of document.querySelectorAll('form') with myArray, but for clarity I'll leave it as is.